# detect when video item change in AVQueuePlayer

Tags: ios, swift

in my project I use AVQueuePlayer for play multiple video, in some case I want to know when current item finish and next item begin. I use Noftification like this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.goToStepTwo), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.player?.currentItem)
```

but this method only work for first item.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using

```
.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.goToStepTwo), name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.player?.currentItem)
```

You're explicitly asking do be notified when `self.player?.currentItem` plays to the end.

To be notified for any item, just use `nil` as the `object`

```
.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.goToStepTwo), name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil)
```

From https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/notificationcenter/1411723-addobserver

> `obj`
>
> The object whose notifications the observer wants to receive; that is, only notifications sent by this sender are delivered to the observer.
>
> If you pass `nil`, the notification center doesn’t use a notification’s sender to decide whether to deliver it to the observer.